# Swapping the numerator and denominator of a natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I have came across a question in which the given answer is:

4 + 10 $\ln{\frac{5}{7}}$,

but my answer was:

4 - 10 $\ln{\frac{7}{5}}$

I know these two answers are equivalent, but how can I mathematically manipulate one of the equations to obtain the other?

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: $a \ln b = \ln b^a$ so $-\ln b = \ln b^{-1} =\ln \frac 1b$.

Comment: 1) $4 + 10\ln 57 = 4+10 \ln \frac 1{\frac 75}=4+10\ln (\frac 75)^{-1}= 4-10\ln \frac 75$.  2) $4 + 10\ln \frac 57=4+10(\ln 5 -\ln 7) = 4-10(\ln 7 - \ln 5) = 4-10\ln \frac 75$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln\frac{5}{7}=\ln5-\ln7=-(\ln7-\ln5)=-\ln\frac{7}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

The constant multiple before a logarithm term can be made the logarithm's argument's exponent.

In this case, taking the -1 multiple of the second Ln can be moved to be the ln's argument's exponent and then the -1 exponent switches the fraction's polarity.